# set workbooks and worksheets returns either "nothing" or 424 run-time error object required

Tags: vba, excel, set

I am desperately hoping someone can help me.  I've been troubleshooting this issue for the last 3 days non-stop.  I am new to VBA so I am sure it has to be something elementary.  Basically I have 2 open workbooks, one holds the data, and the other is where I want to paste some of the data based on an "if, then".  For some reason, I cannot set the workbooks as variables in order to easily reference/update.  I know we will be changing the name of these 2 documents as soon as I am able to go live, so I wanted to just change it in one place instead of all throughout the code.  Below is the code, can someone please tell me what I'm missing?  The comments are included to help make the picture clear.  I look forward to hearing any wisdom that you could impart?

```
Dim I As Integer

'NAMING AND ASSIGNING TYPE WORKBOOKS AND WORKSHEETS FOR EASIER REFERENCE
Dim wbraw As Workbook
Dim wsrawwires As Worksheet
Dim wbdest As Workbook
Dim wsdestwires As Worksheet
Dim wsdestcover As Worksheet

'SETTING LOCATION OF NAMED WORKBOOKS AND WORKSHEETS FOR CODING
Set wbraw = Workbooks("scorecard (raw data) revised.xlsx")
Set wbdest = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm")
Set wsrawwires = wbraw.Sheets("wires")
Set wsdestwires = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
Set wsdestcover = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cover")

'NAMING AND LOCATING VARIABLE FOR CONDITION OF IF STATEMENT
previousyear = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Range("x10")

'NAMING AND LOCATING VARIABLE FOR SOURCE TESTED IN IF STATEMENT
rawwiresfinalrow = wsrawwires.Range("b537").End(xlUp).Row

For I = 3 To rawwiresfinalrow
'CODE FOR PULLING APPLICABLE DATA INTO DESTINATION REPORT
    If wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 5)).Value = previousyear.Value Then
        wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, 5)).Copy
        wsdestwires.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: Where does you error occur? Is it always the same type of error?

Comment: `previousyear = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Range("x10")` Does a Workbook have a `Range` Object?

Comment: it is now giving me a run-time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method.  When I hit debug it highlights the "previousyear = workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").range ("x10")  portion of code.  I have verified that there is a value in cell x10 of the referenced workbook?

Comment: And don't use `Integer` for row counting. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. I recommend always to use `Long` instead of `Integer` because there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all in VBA.

Comment: @Sarai A workbook doesn't have a cell. You need to reverence a worksheet instead.

Comment: Change the Code which is higlighted by the error to `previousyear = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("x10")`

Comment: Marco Getrost-- I am not certain?  I also tried using cells previousyear = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Cells(10, 24) but I'm getting the same error?

Comment: @Sarai. You have to specify the Worksheet you want to access. What is the Worksheet called from which u want to use range x10?

Comment: `Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Worksheets("name of the sheet").Cells(10, 24)`

Comment: @MarcoGetrost .  You are awesome....now I'm getting the error in the "If wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 5)).Value = previousyear.Value Then"  portion of code.  it's like it doesn't recognize the workbooks and worksheets that I previously set?

Comment: define the variable `previousyear` at the beginning with `Dim previousyear As Range` and then define the `previousyear` like this: `Set previousyear = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm").Sheets("Name_of_sheet").Range("x10")`

Comment: `Cells` must be properly qualified with a `Worksheet` object, otherwise it's implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is currently active. If `wsrawwires` isn't the active sheet, then `wsrawwires.Range(Cells(whatever))` will likely blow up, because that's really doing `wsrawwires.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(whatever))`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Actually `Range(Cells(I, 5))` will blow up because range does only accept an address or 2 `Cells` but does not accept **one cells**. The correct way would be to use `Cells` directly without using range at all `wsrawwires.Cells(I, 5).Value`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ gah, yes, absolutely.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost yes, that got me past that line, and just as Mathieu Guindon stated, I cannot reference the set name for wsrawwires because I get an error (even though I've specifically defined wsrawwires as being in a different workbook in the beginning??), I am so confused!  so, I went the long route and changed that line to  If Workbooks("scorecard (raw data) revised.xlsx").Sheets("wires").Range(I, 5).Value = previousyear.Value Then
            wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, 5)).Copy  but I still get an error??  I really appreciate you taking the time to walk me through this?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I've changed it to    Workbooks("scorecard (raw data) revised.xlsx").Sheets("wires").Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, 5)).Copy and still getting the error?

Comment: You apparently did not read what I wrote, nor what @Pᴇʜ replied. Read it again.

Comment: I apologize @MathieuGuindon, I'm very new at this and you're right, I've updated the if statement to   If wsrawwires.Cells(I, 5).Value = previousyear.Value Then    -----now I'm just needing to copy them all. How can I reference the range of cells that I'm wanting copied if I'm not using both range and cell, since I'm wanting to copy all of the applicable rows for columns b through d?  I'm truly thankful for your patience and help with this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, I would always recommend using `Option Explicit`which basically stops the code from running if not all variables are defined. This makes debugging easier and you will find typos straight away.

So use this instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub nameOfSub()

Dim i As Long 'use Long instead of Integer.
Dim rawwiresfinalrow as Long
Dim counter As Long

'NAMING AND ASSIGNING TYPE WORKBOOKS AND WORKSHEETS FOR EASIER REFERENCE
Dim wbraw As Workbook
Dim wsrawwires As Worksheet
Dim wbdest As Workbook
Dim wsdestwires As Worksheet
Dim wsdestcover As Worksheet

Dim previousyear As Range

'SETTING LOCATION OF NAMED WORKBOOKS AND WORKSHEETS FOR CODING
Set wbraw = Workbooks("scorecard (raw data) revised.xlsx")
Set wbdest = Workbooks("scorecard revised.xlsm")
Set wsrawwires = wbraw.Sheets("wires")
Set wsdestwires = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")
Set wsdestcover = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cover")

'NAMING AND LOCATING VARIABLE FOR CONDITION OF IF STATEMENT
Set previousyear = wbdest.Sheets("Enter_your_sheetname_here").Range("x10")

'NAMING AND LOCATING VARIABLE FOR SOURCE TESTED IN IF STATEMENT
rawwiresfinalrow = wsrawwires.Range("b537").End(xlUp).Row

counter = 1
For i = 3 To rawwiresfinalrow
'CODE FOR PULLING APPLICABLE DATA INTO DESTINATION REPORT
    If wsrawwires.Cells(I, 5).Value = previousyear.Value Then
        With wsrawwires
            .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 5)).Copy
        End With
        wsdestwires.Range("A" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: You should change `wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 5)).Value` into `wsrawwires.Cells(I, 5).Value`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks, I didn't catch that.

Comment: it's still giving me an error run-time error 1004 method 'range of object' worksheet failed?

Comment: @Sarai What line?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost     wsrawwires.Range(Cells(I, 2), Cells(I, 5)).Copy    I apologize for the code not being in a gray square, I'm not sure how to make that happen lol!

Comment: @Sarai did you change the big I to a small i?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost I just did, but it keeps changing it back to an uppercase?  that's weird...I didn't even notice it was doing that??

Comment: @MarcoGetrost also, I just noticed that when I use the immediate window to define "I", it is giving a value of "3" not 3 to 530 (which is the rawwiresfinalrow) ?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost that pushed the code through, thank you so much!  What lead you to using the "with" statement?  I love learning lol!  Also, the results do not give all rows that match the criteria, only 1 row out of 20 were pasted?

Comment: @Sarai it's because you always paste to A1 on the `wsdestwires` sheet.

Comment: @MarcoGetrost you are AMAZING!!!  thank you sooo much for being patient with me and walking me through this!!  I've checked the box on the answer...if I could vote a million times I would cause you have saved my bacon! lol!   8-D